# Travelling in Economy (Low Fare) on Norwegian between US and Italy

Tags: international-travel, norwegian-air-shuttle

I am thinking about trying Norwegian from New York to Rome.
What are your experience in terms of how comfortable the flight is? Is it really cramped?
Regarding the meals, I see on [this](https://www.norwegian.com/us/travel-info/on-board/food-and-drinks/international-long-haul-flights/) page that you need to pre-order your meal. Is there a price list anywhere? Are you allowed to bring your own food?

Main question I want an answer for: Do "Low Fare" passengers need to pay for meals? If so, is there a price list anywhere?

Comment: One question at the time please.  Your first question ("is it comfortable") is off-topic for this site because it's completely subjective.  You're always allowed to bring your own food (with some limits, you may get into trouble trying to eat durian or surströmming).

Comment: @gerrit  Thank you for the comment. I edited my question.

Comment: From what I understand, Norwegian is an ultra-low-cost airline, and thus charges for absolutely everything when you buy their lowest fares.

Comment: Recent experience with Norwegian (737-800, BUD-ARN) on Ultra-Low cost: Free wifi, comfortable leg space (I'm 180cm), felt roomier than Ryanair, I could even stretch my legs which isn't always the case with Ryanair. I would pick them over Ryanair, and with the free Wifi, I'd even pick them over some non-ultra-low-cost carriers. KLM etc will obviously have better comfort though. Food and drinks are extra.

Answer (score 4):

While the Economy menu is specifically included for LowFare+ and Flex tickets, it's only available via pre-order for LowFare.

From https://www.norwegian.com/us/travel-info/on-board/food-and-drinks/international-long-haul-flights/

> **LowFare**
>
> If you're flying on a LowFare ticket, our Economy menu is available to
> pre-order. Keep in mind that pre-ordering your meal must be done at
> least 72 hours prior to departure. Don't feel like having a full meal
> on board? The snack bar is open between servings, so you won't go
> hungry.
>
> **LowFare+ and Flex**
>
> If you've booked a LowFare+ or Flex ticket, the Economy menu is
> included for your flight.

https://www.norwegian.com/us/travel-info/on-board/food-and-drinks/international-long-haul-flights/

There's a price list for pre-ordered meals as well as individual snacks and drinks on the Optional service charges page here.

https://www.norwegian.com/us/booking/booking-information/optional-charges/

> **International long haul**
>
> **Pre-ordered meals - LowFare tickets**
>
> - 45 USD per person, each way
>
> **Snacks and drinks on board**
>
> Light meals, snacks and drinks are available for purchase on board
> most flights. Onboard purchases may be charged in a different currency
> than stated below. Prices may change without notice.
>
> - Non-alcoholic drinks: 4 - 5 USD
> - Alcoholic drinks: 7 -  15 USD
> - Snacks: 4 - 8 USD
> - Fresh food: 10 - 11 USD

The Economy menu is described here at Norwegian's site here:

https://www.norwegian.com/us/travel-info/on-board/food-and-drinks/international-long-haul-flights/

> **First service**
>
> - A cold pasta/salad starter
> - For the main course you’ll get either a meat or fish dish with vegetables and potatoes or rice
> - The meal is rounded off with a dessert
> - Coffee/tea is served after the meal
>
> **Second service**
>
> - A snack bag which includes a sandwich, a sweet or savoury treat and a juice box

Comment: I know the point is to get you to buy a more expensive fare or bring your own food, but $45 is a truly incredible price for an airline meal.

Answer (score 2):

As of early 2018, the Norwegian 787's were pretty nice, with more leg room than most economy airlines. Seatguru shows the [seat pitch is 31-32 and width is 17.2](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Norwegian_Air_Shuttle/Norwegian_Air_Shuttle_Boeing_787-8.php). You can find the [airports served by Norwegian 787's on their website](https://www.norwegian.com/en/about/experience-us/dreamliner/#where-we-fly), which includes New York-Rome. I brought my own food.

I also flew Norwegian between other airports not on that list, on [a 737 with less leg room (seat pitch 29-31)](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Norwegian_Air_Shuttle/Norwegian_Air_Shuttle_Boeing_737-800.php).